# select data based on value of a field

Tags: bash, awk, field-codes

I have a file with several entries providing IDs and another file with other entries subdivided in different fields separate by a TAB. I need to select the records of the second file based on matching value of the first file. I have seen on the web that AWK is the right tool (although probably GREP is simpler), but I do not get any output.

For this example, I used arrays rater than files, but in order to use awk I had to create a temporary file. In essence, I need to match the 3rd field of the second file (var2) with the value provided by the first file (var1). The selection form var2 should be: "shameText\t someWhat\t  beta\t  thatIs", from which I print only the first field, so the output should simply be: "shameText". I might have missed the right way to assign arrays, but anyway this example is just a proxy for the real match on files.

The question is: how do a select a row (record) or a single field based on a match between a filed and the value of a variable?

Example:

```
var1="alpha beta gamma delta epsilon"
var2="
'someText somethingElse zeta  someMore'
'sameText someElse  kappa andMore'
'shameText  someWhat  beta  thatIs'
'shortText  moreElse  theta andMore'"
echo $var2 > tempFile
for i in $var1
do
  printf "i is: %s\n" $i
  awk -F\t '$3 == "$i" {print $1}' tempFile
  echo "next item"
done
rm tempFile
```

Comment: If I understood right, you want to search lines in the `var2` which the third field is one of the word in `var1` list, then print only the first field of those lines `grep -f <(tr ' ' '\n' <file-with-IDs) file-with-fields | cut -f1`

Comment: (I should have posted this comment before) Your code works, but there is some corrections. In `echo $var2 > tempfile`  $var2 must be double-quoted to preserve tabs and new lines `echo "$var2" > tempfile`. In the awk line, -F option doesn't need to be set, default awk separators are blank and tab, and variable `$i` must be exposed to the shell `awk '$3 == "'$i'" {print $1}' tempFile` Note that there are double-quotes inside the awk command.

Answer (score 0):

More simple `awk` solution could be comparing $3 with a regex.

`awk '$3 ~ /alpha|beta|gamma|delta|epsilon/ {print $1}' tempFile`

Passing the list as `$var1`

`awk '$3 ~ /'"${var1// /|}"'/ {print $1}' tempFile`

If $var1 is a file, you could pass it to awk with cat

`awk '$3 ~ /'"$(cat IDs|tr ' ' '|')"'/ {print $1}' tempFile`

Comment: Thanks Paulo, I always get confused with the Bash's quotes. The second solution you give me works just fine. But after all, I think grep is easier.

Comment: for the record, the main problem with my real data was that I exported them from windows to linux. I had to do: r -d '\r' < file_dos > file_linux to have the grep command working.